# How do you select a document from a Google Drive popup selection window in python's selenium package?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I working on a beta proof of concept automation project where, at this stage, I am trying to go into a Google drive pop-up window and select a particular document and submit it. This is what the popup window looks like.

[image]

Here is the HTML for the first section, highlighted:
[image]

Here is the HTML for the second section, highlighted:
[image]

I have tried a few different driver.find_element_by_xpath and ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys....) methods but keep getting errors. Note, I am in the right driver window. I did figure that out. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Update: For example, when I try and run this code:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("Od-lh-Jf-O-Ah-Bh").click()
```

I get this error output:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".Od-lh-Jf-O-Ah-Bh"}
```

Answer (score 1):

**DISCLAIMER**

Okay. So, I was not able to get your pop-up to appear or you code to appear; but, I did go onto my own Google Drive and I was able to select a photo. So, hopefully, this technique might be able to help you or guide you to the correct solution.

Based on the `HTML` that was rendered to me, I was able to create the following `xpath`

```
//div[@role='main' and not(@style)]//c-wiz[@aria-multiselectable='true']//c-wiz[@data-node-index]//div[@role='row']
```

**Explanation**

When I was reviewing the code that was presented to me, I noticed that some of the page has some repetitive `classes`; namely `role` and `style` for starters. So, based off of that, I noticed that if I had a file in my folder, my `div` was not going to have a `@style='display: none;'` or `@style` tag,

Once I opened my Google Developer Tools ( F12 ), I typed into the `xpath` search bar: `//div[@role='main' and not(@style)]` and I got 1 of 1.

After that, I started looking down into the code and I noticed that a `c-wiz` had the `class` `aria-multiselectable` and that was the only one. So, I added `//c-wiz[@aria-multiselectable='true']` and the result was, still, 1 of 1

Then, I dived further into the `HTML` code and saw that, if I have multiple photos, each of them were located in a `div` with the `class` `role`. Based off of that, I was able to navigate between the 2 photos using this `xpath`

```
//div[@role='main' and not(@style)]//c-wiz[@aria-multiselectable='true']//c-wiz[@data-node-index]//div[@role='row']
```

The `xpath` above results in 1 of 2. So, this `xpath` means that you can select any photo or, I assume, document that displays in your folder. From there, once you click on the photo or document using the following `xpath`

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@role='main' and not(@style)]//c-wiz[@aria-multiselectable='true']//c-wiz[@data-node-index]//div[@role='row'][1]").click()
```

You will see that the `class` `aria-selected` is changed to `True`. From there, your `Select` button should, theoretically, not have the `@disabled` tag anymore.

**Image**
[image]